# 74HC76 integrated really use Vcc pin?

Tags: wiring, ttl, 5v

I'm building a simple `ring counter` with two jk flip-flop. I'm using [`74HC76`](http://www.classiccmp.org/rtellason/chipdata/mc74hc76.pdf) integrated that contains two jk.

This is the integrated pinout:

[image]

This is my schematic (very basic):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXO4Fg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To build a working circuit it's necessary that you connect `pin 5` to Vcc (5V) and `pin 13` to GND. But...

The problem is that in the circuit that I'm observing on my desk **the ring counter only works when `pin 5` (Vcc) is unwired**. It means that if I wire pin 5 to Vcc I got always 10 output. Is that possible?
If no what's the matter of my circuit?

I've tried all:

- I've substituted the integrated -> same problem
- I've checked another time pin connection -> same problem
- I've changed wires -> same problem

**EDIT**: I initialize the first jk with `1` using a button and preset and clear pin.

Comment: First: Do not, ever, disconnect the VCC pin when debugging, because that breaks chips. Second: what are you doing with the Preset and Clear pins? (i.e. J and K propagate 1 to 1, if you don't preset and clear one on initialisation, you will not know what happens, but them both starting with 1/0 or both with 0/1 is quite likely)

Comment: JK1 and JK2 need to initialize in opposite states, don't they?  How do you ensure this? Also, you should use resistors in series with the LEDs

Comment: @Asmyldof: Thanks for your advice. About Preset and Clear pin I'm managing them well: I've a button that sets the starting 1 in the first jk, so I think that the problem isn't about Preset or Clear pin.

Comment: @user28910 : I've just edited my question

Comment: On CMOS parts, all unused inputs must be connected, directly or through a resistor, to either Vcc or ground, whichever is required to make the part work as required.  For the Preset pin where you have a switch to pull it to ground, you must also have a resistor (5K - 10K) to Vcc to ensure the preset pin is high when the switch is not taking it low.

Comment: @PeterBennett your method work! I forgot to manage the Preset and Clear pins when the button wasn't pushed, so the jk can't count correctly because these pins aren't to 1. Thank you, If you want to add an answer below, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a resistor in series with each LED is is likely that the corresponding Q output is being dragged down to a voltage that is not high enough to be recognized as a legitimate high level by the following J input.

Answer (score 2):

On CMOS parts, all unused inputs must be connected, directly or through a resistor, to either Vcc or ground, whichever is required to make the part work as required. For the Preset pin where you have a switch to pull it to ground, you must also have a resistor (5K - 10K) to Vcc to ensure the preset pin is high when the switch is not taking it low.